# Не получается включить нужное разрешение на ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: linux

На ПК стоит две ОС: Windows 10 и Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
На винде спокойно стоит разрешение 1920x1080, а вот на бубунте выше чем 1280х720, только 1600х900 (но это разрешение не подходит мне,а 1280х720 - ужасное качество). Пытался через терминал добавить нужное разрешение - не помогло. Драйвера проприетарные для nvidia.

Comment: Если в nvidia-settings нет вашего разрешения, значит его нет. Скажите спасибо nvidia. Лично у меня 1920x1080 [доступно](https://imgur.com/B75I7cS.png), но, само собой, это зависит от модели видеокарты.

Comment: Кстати, у меня наоборот нет разрешения 1600х900 и оно для меня самое комфортное! С удовольствием поменялся бы :D

Comment: самое комфортное разрешение - это разрешения монитора. не стоит натягивать 1600х900 на монитор 1920x1080 и извращаться с 1920x1080 на матрице 1600х900. Ставьте родное разрешение, а остальное делатся масштабом шрифтов и сраниц.

Comment: А на открытых дровах - всё плохо?